# JOptionPane has no effect when look and feel set

Tags: java, windows, swing, look-and-feel

I set below look and feel for main class.

**Base class code:**

```
 static
{
    try
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.error("Error setting look and feel!", exception);
    }
}
```

**Sub class code:**

```
   int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(panel,
            message,
            "",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            formattedOptions,
            formattedOptions[0]);
```

The windows look and feel is not get set as windows for JOptionPane rather it's showing java default look and feel.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: just only for JOptionPane,other components are in correct look and feel or not

Comment: Yes All other components are behaving as per setting look and feel in main class. but the JOPtion is not?

Comment: Did you set the look and feel **before** calling the JOptionPane?

Comment: Yes I tring the below way as well...


 try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {               
        }

        int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(panel,
                message,
                "",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                formattedOptions,
                formattedOptions[0]);

Comment: Can you post and [SSCCE](www.sscce.org) not just fragment from your code?

Comment: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");`  That is fragile, and will fail on OS X & *nix (fortunately).

Comment: Yes Now I am getting proper look and feel which i applied..
but the JOptionPane is showing without title bar.
could you please help me

Comment: _When_ do you set the LnF? Did you do _any_ UI work before?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely timing related. Try setting laf using vm arg:

```
-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
```